# OnTriggerExit being called by collider not marked as trigger error Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, triggers, collider

I have a hirarchy like so:
[image]
in the parent i have a the following components:
[image]
the child called `DropDetector` has a collider marked as a trigger. and the child called `drop_area` also has a collider but this one IS NOT marked as a trigger. But at the moment my OntriggerEnter and Exit functions are being called from the `drop_area` collider eventhough it is NOT marked as a trigger. Why is this happening? And how do i stop it from happening?

The `DropArea` script and rigidbody are attached to the parent called `IncrementA_DropArea`

If anymore information or clarification is needed pls let me know so i can clarify!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working as intended. From the unity docs on [`MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit(Collider)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit.html):

> This message is sent to the trigger and the collider that touches the trigger.

You can not avoid this from being called on `drop_area`'s `MonoBehaviour`s.

However, in the implementation of `MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerExit(Collider)`, you can check first if the called `MonoBehaviour`'s collider is not a trigger, and exit the method if so:

```
public Collider myCollider;

...

myCollider = GetComponent<Collider>();

...

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) 
{
    if (!myCollider.isTrigger) 
    {
        return;
    } 

    // Do stuff for trigger here.
}
```